# Button click() in Selenium Webdriver doesnt return search result

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am new to Selenium.

To learn more about selenium, I started automating a flight search flow of the website "https://www.findmyfare.com/" using Selenium web driver in Java.

I was able to perform the search button click. But it directs to a error page instead of producing result for my search criteria.

When I perform the search manually, it works fine.

Could someone help me to sort this problem?

N.B. This search button is not a type of "submit". So, i used click() method.
(I tried with submit() as well, there was no difference as well).

Following is the code segment to trigger the search.

```
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class FlightSearchWD
{
public WebDriver driver = null;
public String baseUrl;

@Test
public void testFlightSearchWD()
{

    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.findmyfare.com/");
    driver.findElement(By.id("from_1")).click();
    WebElement cleartext = driver.findElement(By.id("from_1"));
    cleartext.clear();

    WebElement FromCity = driver.findElement(By.id("from_1"));
    FromCity.sendKeys("Auckland, New Zealand (AKL)");

    driver.findElement(By.id("to_1")).click();
    WebElement cleartext1 = driver.findElement(By.id("to_1"));
    cleartext1.clear();
    WebElement ToCity = driver.findElement(By.id("to_1"));
    ToCity.sendKeys("Colombo, Sri Lanka (CMB)");
    WebElement FromDate = driver.findElement(By.id("date_1"));
    FromDate.click();

    WebElement datepicker = driver.findElement(By.id("ui-datepicker-div"));
    List<WebElement> rows = datepicker.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
    List<WebElement> columns = datepicker.findElements(By.tagName("td"));

    for (WebElement cell : columns)
    {
        // Select 20th Date
        if (cell.getText().equals("20"))
        {
            cell.findElement(By.linkText("20")).click();
            break;
        }
    }
    // select to date

    WebElement ToDate = driver.findElement(By.id("date_2"));
    ToDate.click();

    WebElement datepicker2 = driver.findElement(By.id("ui-datepicker-div"));
    List<WebElement> rows1 = datepicker2.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
    List<WebElement> columns1 = datepicker2.findElements(By.tagName("td"));

    for (WebElement cell1 : columns1)
    {
        // Select 20th Date
        if (cell1.getText().equals("25"))
        {
            cell1.findElement(By.linkText("25")).click();
            break;
        }
    }

    WebElement ClickTravellers = driver.findElement(By.id("PopS"));
    ClickTravellers.click();
    addAdults();
    addChildren();
    addInfant();

    WebElement clickSearch = driver.findElement(By.id("search_flight_submit"));
    clickSearch.click();

}

private void addAdults()
{
    while (true)
    {
        WebElement popOverBtnGrp = driver
                .findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='btn-group col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12']"));
        if (popOverBtnGrp.isDisplayed())
        {
            try
            {
                WebElement NoOfTravellers = driver.findElement(By.xpath(
                        "//button[@class='btn add_people  ripple-effect btn-default btn-sm col-xs-2 col-md-4 col-sm-4']"));
                for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
                {
                    NoOfTravellers.click();
                }
                break;
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}

private void addChildren()
{
    while (true)
    {
        WebElement popOverBtnGrp = driver
                .findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='btn-group col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12']"));
        if (popOverBtnGrp.isDisplayed())
        {
            try
            {
                WebElement NoOfTravellers = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class=' add_people btn btn-default btn-sm  ripple-effect col-xs-2 col-md-4 col-sm-4' and @data-id='childrens']"));
                for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
                {
                    NoOfTravellers.click();
                }

                break;
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }

    }

}


private void addInfant()
{
    while (true)
    {
        WebElement popOverBtnGrp = driver
                .findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='btn-group col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12']"));
        if (popOverBtnGrp.isDisplayed())
        {
            try
            {
                WebElement NoOfTravellers =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='add_people btn btn-default btn-sm   ripple-effect col-xs-2 col-md-4 col-sm-4' and @data-id='infants']"));
                for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
                {
                    NoOfTravellers.click();
                }

                break;
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }

     }  

 }


}
```

Comment: Please add your code to the question

Comment: I added the code related to triggering the search.

Comment: Since button click is redirecting to error page, button click is working fine. There must be some other error. Can you please share your entire search code snippet?

Comment: Entire code added.

Comment: This code works for me. Can you try adding some delay using wait command? It might be loading issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Asha, I am also new to selenium webdriver and learnt a lot from this query and finally finds the solution.

```
import java.util.List;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class FlightSearchWD {
public WebDriver driver = null;
public String baseUrl;

@Test
public void testFlightSearchWD() throws InterruptedException {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.findmyfare.com/");
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    WebElement from1 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions
            .presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("from_1")));
    from1.click();
    from1.clear();
    from1.sendKeys("AKL");
    from1.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
    driver.findElement(By.id("to_1")).click();
    WebElement cleartext1 = driver.findElement(By.id("to_1"));
    cleartext1.clear();
    WebElement ToCity = driver.findElement(By.id("to_1"));
    ToCity.sendKeys("CMB");
    ToCity.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='trip_types']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("date_1")).click();
    List<WebElement> total_date = driver
            .findElements(By
                    .xpath("//div[@class='panel-body']/div[@class='pull-left col-md-6 pull-left-first']/table[1]//td"));
    int total_date_size = total_date.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < total_date_size; i++) {
        String date = total_date.get(i).getText();
        if (date.equalsIgnoreCase("20")) {
            total_date.get(i).click();
            break;
        }
    }
    driver.findElement(By.id("date_2")).click();
    List<WebElement> total_date1 = driver
            .findElements(By
                    .xpath("//div[@class='panel-body']/div[@class='pull-left col-md-6 pull-left-first']/table[1]//td"));
    int total_date_size1 = total_date1.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < total_date_size1; i++) {
        String date1 = total_date1.get(i).getText();
        if (date1.equalsIgnoreCase("25")) {
            total_date1.get(i).click();
            break;
        }
    }
    WebElement ClickTravellers = driver.findElement(By.id("PopS"));
    ClickTravellers.click();
    addAdults();
    addChildren();
    addInfant();

    WebElement clickSearch = driver.findElement(By
            .id("search_flight_submit"));
    clickSearch.click();

}

private void addAdults() {
    while (true) {
        WebElement popOverBtnGrp = driver
                .findElement(By
                        .xpath("//div[@class='btn-group col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12']"));
        if (popOverBtnGrp.isDisplayed()) {
            try {
                WebElement NoOfTravellers = driver
                        .findElement(By
                                .xpath("//button[@class='btn add_people  ripple-effect btn-default btn-sm col-xs-2 col-md-4 col-sm-4']"));
                for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                    NoOfTravellers.click();
                }
                break;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}

private void addChildren() {
    while (true) {
        WebElement popOverBtnGrp = driver
                .findElement(By
                        .xpath("//div[@class='btn-group col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12']"));
        if (popOverBtnGrp.isDisplayed()) {
            try {
                WebElement NoOfTravellers = driver
                        .findElement(By
                                .xpath("//button[@class=' add_people btn btn-default btn-sm  ripple-effect col-xs-2 col-md-4 col-sm-4' and @data-id='childrens']"));
                for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                    NoOfTravellers.click();
                }

                break;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }

    }

}

private void addInfant() {
    while (true) {
        WebElement popOverBtnGrp = driver
                .findElement(By
                        .xpath("//div[@class='btn-group col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12']"));
        if (popOverBtnGrp.isDisplayed()) {
            try {
                WebElement NoOfTravellers = driver
                        .findElement(By
                                .xpath("//button[@class='add_people btn btn-default btn-sm   ripple-effect col-xs-2 col-md-4 col-sm-4' and @data-id='infants']"));
                for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                    NoOfTravellers.click();
                }

                break;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }

    }

}

}
```

Please let me know if you have any issues regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is very good for emulating the user interaction in a browser. However, by default the commands follow a simple order. You load a page in the driver. As soon as the page is "finished" loading, it will then perform the actions you tell it to immediately. If you say find an element, it goes through the DOM trying to find a matching element to the By locator. If it finds one it returns it. If it doesn't find one, it throws an exception. While this is great as a default for the selenium project or for very static web sites, more often nowadays web sites are dynamic. The page will be considered "loaded" but most of the content is being fetched via asynchronous calls. This is because it gives users a sense that the page is "snappy" by allowing interaction with portions that are "above the fold" or the key content and not make them wait for sections they might not care about. Unfortunately, this makes automating modern web sites more difficult. In general, it is best when using Selenium on a non-static web site to wrap all interactions with a WebDriverWait to make sure that the element is in the condition you expect it to be before trying to click it. Simple example of waiting for conditions below.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class FooTest {

    @Test
    public void foo() {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.findmyfare.com/");
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("from_1")))
                                     .click();
        // ... etc
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Note that the number "10" in the constructor to the web driver wait above is the timeout in seconds. If no element with the matching id is found in a clickable state within 10 seconds, an exception will be thrown.

Comment: does setting the implicitly_wait condition for the driver itself remove the need to wait for individual elements?

Answer (score 0):

The others are correct on saying that there should be waits in your element calls. You've managed to somehow workaround it by doing the while loops but waits are almost always better. I downloaded your code and ran it and the problem that you are facing is not actually something that is directly related to selenium.

So, you mentioned that instead of going to the results page it goes to an error page and I think that is the expected behavior from the website's point of view. My best guess is that they have a detection if the 'user' navigating their website is a 'bot' or not and if it is a 'bot', then goes to a different page instead of the regular search results page. Try another website to test your selenium script and I'm pretty sure that it work.

Anyway, I've created a selenium framework targeted for beginners and helps you avoid the problems that was mentioned here. It will even auto-close the browser for you once your test is done. Here's a translation of your code above using the easytest framework.

```
    @Test
public void testFindMyFare() throws Exception {
    try(EasyTest easy = new EasyTest(DriverType.CHROME)) {

        // start
        easy.start("https://www.findmyfare.com/");

        // homepage
        easy.newPage(page -> {

            page.typeText("#from_1", "Auckland, New Zealand (AKL)");
            page.typeText("#to_1", "Colombo, Sri Lanka (CMB)");

            // click from date slector and select 20th
            page.click("#date_1");
            page.executeIn("#ui-datepicker-div", container -> {
               container.click(":20"); 
            });

            // click to date slector and select 25th
            page.click("#date_2");
            page.executeIn("#ui-datepicker-div", container -> {
                container.click(":25"); 
            });

            // click travellers
            page.click("#PopS");

            // add people
            page.executeIn(".popover", container -> {
                container.click("button[data-id='adults'].add_people");
                container.click("button[data-id='childrens'].add_people");
                container.click("button[data-id='infants'].add_people");
            });

            // click find flight button
            page.clickButton("#search_flight_submit");

        });

    }
}
```

If you find the test above easier to read and follow, you can download the easytest framework at https://github.com/codezombies/easytest. Let me know if I can help you in anyway learning selenium.

Comment: I did the same test by using selenium IDE and it works fine.

Comment: based on the answer above, and i tested this myself, you need to press ENTER on the textbox. I think what's happening is that the values on the textboxes were not being set properly if ENTER is not pressed